# Join an array of strings

Tags: d

The question is simple. I'm looking for an easy and efficient way of joining an array of strings (or arrays of any other type, for that matter, since strings are an alias for `char[]`), with an optional separator.

In JavaScript, this functionality would already exist with the `join` method. Being new to D, I failed to find something as easy as that in the standard library. It would be too bad if I had to implement a utility function myself.

So instead of something like this:

```
string merge (const string arr[] , const string separator) {
    if (arr.length == 0) return "";
    string r = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1 ; i < arr.length ; i++) {
        r ~= separator ~ arr[i];
    }
    return r;
}
```

What would an experienced D programmer do?

Comment: [`std.array.join`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_array.html#.join)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a D programmer, but I'll take a crack at it, the library reference [has a join method](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_array.html#.join).

From the docs:

```
const string[] arr = ["apple", "banana"];
assert(arr.join(",") == "apple,banana");
assert(arr.join() == "applebanana");
```

Comment: Indeed, I must have overlooked that function. Great. :)

Comment: The tricky thing with D strings is they aren't all that special, they are arrays and the stdlib tries to be generic, so a lot of their functions are found in `std.array` or `std.algorithm`. But if you import those two as well as `std.string`, you'll probably find most other language's string class features to be available to you too.

Answer (score 3):

See also `std.algorithm.joiner` for a version that is lazy and doesn't allocate any memory.